# return all the array between one hour via php

Tags: php, json, search, twitter

lets say we do some search useing search api then it retuns something like this in json.

```
  'results' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[9]
          public 'from_user_id_str' => string '57393273' (length=8)
          public 'profile_image_url' => string 'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1150792547/49146_1365401218_7951632_q_normal.jpg' (length=83)
          public 'created_at' => string 'Mon, 06 Jun 2011 04:01:36 +0000' (length=31)
          public 'from_user' => string 'primalokomotif' (length=14)
          public 'id_str' => string '77585906684526592' (length=17)
          public 'metadata' => 
            object(stdClass)[10]
              public 'result_type' => string 'recent' (length=6)
          public 'to_user_id' => null
          public 'text' => string 'RT @detikcom kober siap perkenalkan ajaran klub suami suami takut istri' (length=71)
          public 'id' => float 7.7585906684527E+16
          public 'from_user_id' => int 57393273
          public 'geo' => null
          public 'iso_language_code' => string 'id' (length=2)
          public 'to_user_id_str' => null
          public 'source' => string '&lt;a href=&quot;http://mobile.twitter.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Mobile Web&lt;/a&gt;' (length=97)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[11]
          public 'from_user_id_str' => string '278060132' (length=9)
          public 'profile_image_url' => string 'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1355377589/296218442_normal.jpg' (length=66)
          public 'created_at' => string 'Mon, 06 Jun 2011 04:01:34 +0000' (length=31)
          public 'from_user' => string 'kaka_kecil' (length=10)
          public 'id_str' => string '77585897637412864' (length=17)
          public 'metadata' => 
            object(stdClass)[12]
              public 'result_type' => string 'recent' (length=6)
          public 'to_user_id' => null
          public 'text' => string 'RT @detikcom: 'Milan Tak Pernah Inginkan Hamsik' http://de.tk/dP7Cs via @detiksport' (length=83)
          public 'id' => float 7.7585897637413E+16
          public 'from_user_id' => int 278060132
          public 'geo' => null
          public 'iso_language_code' => string 'id' (length=2)
          public 'to_user_id_str' => null
          public 'source' => string '&lt;a href=&quot;http://ubersocial.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;ÃœberSocial&lt;/a&gt;' (length=94)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[13]
          public 'from_user_id_str' => string '185984810' (length=9)
          public 'profile_image_url' => string 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1368466468/a_normal.jpg' (length=58)
          public 'created_at' => string 'Mon, 06 Jun 2011 04:01:31 +0000' (length=31)
          public 'from_user' => string 'tiayeeeaah' (length=10)
          public 'id_str' => string '77585887143276544' (length=17)
          public 'metadata' => 
            object(stdClass)[14]
              public 'result_type' => string 'recent' (length=6)
          public 'to_user_id' => null
          public 'text' => string 'hmm..hmm.. -___-&quot; RT @detikcom: Bandung Siap Perkenalkan Ajaran Klub Istri Taat Suami http://bit.ly/kCcOsG' (length=111)
          public 'id' => float 7.7585887143277E+16
          public 'from_user_id' => int 185984810
          public 'geo' => null
          public 'iso_language_code' => string 'id' (length=2)
          public 'to_user_id_str' => null
          public 'source' => string '&lt;a href=&quot;http://seesmic.com/seesmic_desktop/sd2&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Seesmic Desktop&lt;/a&gt;' (length=115)
      3 => etc
```

**how can we return arrays that have date less then one hour ? or filter it?** maybe something like do a search then returns all the array that have strtotime(created_at) < strtotime("+1 Hours")

*edit

like [How can I use the Twitter Search API to return all tweets that match my search query, posted only within the last five seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206170/how-can-i-use-the-twitter-search-api-to-return-all-tweets-that-match-my-search-qu) 
but there is no answer doing this.

thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're looking to return only those that have `created_at` within the past hour? I like to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) when I can.

```
function filterWithinHour($obj)
{
    return (strtotime($obj->created_at) > strtotime('-1 hour'));
}

$recent = array_filter($results, 'filterWithinHour');
```

If you ever need need to pass it a certain time (instead of assuming *now*), you might want to just loop through the array manually rather than mess with trying to pass a time parameter to the callback with a global variable. I hate globals used like that.

Comment: @wiseguy how can we do something like array_filter($results, 'this->filterWithinHour()'); ?

Comment: ah i see array($this,"callback_function") anyway it work so far, lets wait for another way of achieving this.

Comment: @Adam That's not how that works. The callback function isn't a class method; it's a standalone function that you call by name as in the above example.

Comment: @Adam Right. Another way is to loop through them manually as I mentioned, but it's less awesome than using `array_filter()`. :-) I can give an example of that, too, if you want.

Comment: @wiseguy peformance? i think array_filter is more rocking!, dont you think ? or maybe looping is faster

Comment: @Adam I'd guess `array_filter()` might be a tad faster, but it's not going to be fast enough to make a huge difference unless you're running this like 100,000 times at once. We could run a little test to find out. (I may do that tomorrow.)

Answer (score 2):

The [Twitter Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) has a `since_id` that could help you:

> Returns results with an ID greater
>   than (that is, more recent than) the
>   specified ID. There are limits to the
>   number of Tweets which can be accessed
>   through the API. If the limit of
>   Tweets has occured since the since_id,
>   the since_id will be forced to the
>   oldest ID available.

If you poll every hour, you effectively get the posts of the last hour. If the service is down, you still won't miss any tweets since you could go back several days.

Comment: `If you poll every hour, you effectively get the posts of the last hour.` i still dont get it, yes they have a since id but how can we know a tweet is less then an hour with since id ?

Comment: The id of the most recent post of your previous request is the `id` (or `id_str` of the first tweet in the array. If you poll Twitter once every hour and use the `id` of the first tweet you got from the previous request as `since_id`, you only get tweets that are newer. If you poll every hour, that means you get the tweets of the last hour.

Comment: ahhh i see.. but we have to store / cache the since id right? then wait for an hour to do that.

Comment: +1 Good idea. If this method is fitting for how the API is being queried, this is probably the preferred way to do it.