# tweets on last moments with twitter search api

Tags: php, api, search, curl, twitter

Well, what I'm trying to do is quite obvious. I am receiving tweets as shown below :

```
$options .=  'q='.urlencode($hash_tag);
$options .=  '&page=15';
$options .=  '&rpp=100';
$options .=  '&result_type=recent';

$url = 'https://search.twitter.com/search.atom?'.$options ;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$xml = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$affected = 0;
$twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($twelement->entry as $entry) {
    $text = trim($entry->title);
    $author = trim($entry->author->name);
    $time = strtotime($entry->published);
    $id = $entry->id;
    echo '<hr>';

    echo "Yazan : ".$author;
    echo "</br>";
    echo "Tarih : ".date('Ymd H:i:s',$time);
    echo "</br>";
    echo "Tweet : ".$text;
    echo "</br>";
}
```

and as you can check on this link : [linkToTrial](http://filkulak.com/twitter.php?hashtag=D%C3%BCr%C3%BCstOlmamGerekirse) I can receive tweets. But they are so old for me! I want to receive tweets in last moments, at least in last 5 mins. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206170/how-can-i-use-the-twitter-search-api-to-return-all-tweets-that-match-my-search-q) it says

> This sounds like something you can do on your end, as created_at is one of the fields returned in the result set. Just do your query, and only use the ones that are within the last 5 seconds.

but when you check my example, you will see that I'm not even receiving the last tweets. Where am I doing wrong? Where?

Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks for your responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a deprecated API (search.twitter.com) that will cease functioning on May 7, 2013 -- you'll want to move to the v1.1 Search API -- see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweet for docs.

It looks like the specific reason you're getting older results with this query is that you're starting on page 15 -- the end of the result set. The most recent tweets will be at the beginning of the result set -- page 1.

In API v1.1, the concept of paging no longer exists for the Search API. Instead, you navigate through the result set using since_id and max_id, details here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines

Comment: I couldn't see the first page, it says Page not found.